# snap nextcloud inside lxd, apparmor fail

Tags: nextcloud, apparmor

I've got these fails with my nextcloud service which runs in LXD container via snap

```
audit: type=1400 audit(1617309095.824:9617): apparmor="DENIED" operation="ptrace" namespace="root//lxd-nextcloud_<var-snap-lxd-common-lxd>" profile="snap.nextcloud.nextcloud-cron" pid=12317 comm="ps" requested_mask="read" denied_mask="read" peer="unconfined"

audit: type=1400 audit(1617309095.828:9625): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" namespace="root//lxd-nextcloud_<var-snap-lxd-common-lxd>" profile="snap.nextcloud.nextcloud-cron" name="/proc/199/cmdline" pid=12317 comm="ps" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000000 ouid=1000100
```